# On Firefox on Android, how to disable DNS over HTTPS and do normal DNS lookups via port 53?

Tags: firefox-for-android, dns

I want Firefox on Android to be able to browse to local domain names on my LAN: http://koffiezetapparaat.lan should resolve to http://192.168.1.120 for instance.

This works on desktop Firefox, but doesn't work on Firefox on Android. I suspect that this is because of DNS over HTTPS.

What I tried:
I installed Firefox Beta on Android, went to about:config and set `network.trr.mode` to `5` as described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https#w_manually-enabling-and-disabling-dns-over-https). Then, I removed all DNS cache present in Firefox on Android itself.

Then, I 'hard reloaded' http://koffiezetapparaat.lan by long pressing the reload button.

I still get a 404.

Network traffic analysis with `tcpdump` on my OpenWrt router showed no port 53 traffic, but a lot of port 443 traffic.

Please bear in mind that navigating to http://koffiezetapparaat on Chrome on Android works as it should, it resolves to http://192.168.1.120.

I supect that Firefox on Android still uses DNS over HTTPS and want to know a definitive way of disabling that.

Comment: Disable Private DNS (DoT) on Android 9+. It sends encrypted DNS traffic over port 853.